# How to remove IE "delay" to execute my script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, jsfiddle

The "delay" is causing a problem when i scroll to left my table.

Problem is the "delay" is showing a animation on scroll left, and i need to remove this animation or remove "delay".

In Chrome the code execute perfectly, but not in IE 10 or less.

Here is the code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zjk234p/1/).

Javascript:

```
$(".out").scroll(function () {
   $('.table-1').css('left', $(".out").scrollLeft());
});
```

Comment: Which version of IE? I am checking on chrome and IE 11 and its working fine. Or maybe i am not understanding your issue.

Comment: We are using IE 10 or less.